# LLVM Basic Program : Linker Error

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-gcc, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am just getting started with llvm.

Here's code I am trying to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"


int main()
{
  llvm::LLVMContext& context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
  llvm::Module* module = new llvm::Module("top", context);
  llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(context); 

  module->dump( );
}
```

when i compile with :

```
llvm-g++ try.cpp  -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
```

I get the a.out file. No worries.

But, I am interested in getting the LLVM IR file.So, I compiled with

```
llvm-g++ try.cpp  -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -S -emit-llvm 
lli try.s
```

I get an error saying

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_ZN4llvm16getGlobalContextEv' which could not be resolved!
```

The command :

```
llvm-g++ try.cpp  -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` -S -emit-llvm
```

leaves me with several warnings and when i execute the resultant .s file with lli , I get the same error as before.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I just answered your other question, and found this one which gives more details about your issue. However, I managed to get this program working with clang ver. 3.3, using exactly the command line I gave in my answer. Which version of llvm do you use?

Comment: Hi didierc.I use llvm 3.4.2. I want to generate the .s file. How do i do it ?

Comment: See my updated answer to the other question. My system sports a `clang++` program rather than `llvm-g++`, and I used `--cppflags` instead of `--cxxflags`, but otherwise it should be the same. The `-D` defines are actually generated by `llvm-config`, you don't need to write them explicitely.